# CSS rules not matching? Why not?

Tags: css

OK, in theory this should be an easy one, hopefully I'm just missing something obvious here. I have the following HTML markup:

```
<ul id="cPlayControlRack">
    <li class="cplaybutton"></li>
    <li class="CpauseButton CplayHidden"></li>
    <li class="CplaySkipBack"></li>
    <li class="CplaySkipForward"></li>
    <li class="CplayVolumeIcon"></li>
    <li class="CplayVolumeSlide"></li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#cPlayControlRack{
    height:28px;
}
#cPlayControlRack li{
    width:29px !important;
    height:28px !important;
    background-image:url(background:url(i/playersprite.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
}
.cplaybutton{background-position:0 0;}
.CpauseButton{background-position:30px 0;}
.CplaySkipBack{background-position:60px 0;}
.CplaySkipForward{background-position:90px 0;}
.CplayVolumeIcon{background-position:120px 0;}
.CplayVolumeSlide{background-position:150px 0;}
```

For some reason, the first rule is matching. #cPlayControlRack is making the `UL` 28px high. However, none of the other rules are matching, so the sprite isn't being shown, and the lis are being given no height or width.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4r2jm/

Edit: My markup is dynamically generated, not that that should make a difference AFAIK.

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual page or create a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a syntax error on line 7:

```
background-image:url(background:url(i/playersprite.png);
```

should be:

```
background-image:url('i/playersprite.png');
```

Comment: Derp, thanks. I'll accept in 2 minutes.